# Adding elements that stick to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
(100..999).each do |x| 
  (100..999).each do |y|

    z = x * y
    a = []

    if z.to_s.reverse == z.to_s
        a.push(z)
    end

    puts a

  end
end
```

This code is probably absolutely horrible but I'm having issues getting values to "stick" to my array. Whenever I run the code it returns all the numbers as an array with a single value in and I'm unsure as to why, any explanation of why and how to fix this would be nice. More of a learning exercise than anything.

Comment: Indenting your code would make it much easier to follow. Otherwise, it's not horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `a = []` outside your blocks, like this:

```
a = []

(100..999).each do |x| 
  (100..999).each do |y|

    z = x * y

    a.push(z) if z.to_s.reverse == z.to_s

  end
end

puts a
```

If you fail to do that, a new array will be made during each loop. To understand this, you should look into documentation about scopes. If you define the `a`variable inside the each scope, it will be local to that scope, and that's why your values don't "stick" -> persist.

Comment: I see your point but it doesn't appear to be working. When the array was inside the scope it would print out the values fine however with your change it prints many of the same value and takes much longer, I've not actually seen it finish.

Comment: Because of the way you've written your code. Using puts, outputs the array elements line by line during each loop. I'll modify the code and show you what should work.

Comment: Thanks man. This was really frustrating and I had no clue what I was messing up with. Sloppy code but I guess it'll only improve :)

Comment: You should use `p` instead of `puts` if you wish to only inspect the array, it gets printed as it would look in ruby code instead of printing each element individually.

Comment: I see, I'll take that into account next time I do something. I'll stop bothering you and look around at p vs puts. Can't thank you enough :)!

Comment: There you go. You deserve it.